# Не строгое сравнивание

Tags: javascript

Почему это сравнение `[0] == false` вернет правду?

Comment: Потому что не надо использовать нестрогое сравнение xD `[0] == 0` истина, а 0 == false, поэтому [0] == false - истина.

Comment: Почитайте про неявное преобразование типов в JS (вот здесь, например: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/347866/)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, не всегда из `A == B` и `B==C` следует, что `A==C` :)

Answer (score 0):

Очень забавно, то что меня заминусовали, и написали банальные вещи, а мне хотелось понять как это работает под капотом

Если кратко, то в этом кейсе обо значения приводятся к числу и становятся 0 -ми

Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](https://overcoder.net/q/629367/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2)

Comment: Я писал развёрнутый ответ, но не успел вопрос закрыли....

Comment: Хороший вопрос)
И так начнём по порядку.
Для начала надо понять что `[0] == false` - не то же самое что и `Boolean([0]) == false или !![0] == false`. В первом случае вызывается метод [array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString), что возаращает нам `'0'`. Во втором случае у нас получится `true == false`, что вернёт нам `false`, т.к. все объекты и массивы - это true.

Comment: Извините, я успел найти ответ)

Comment: Там единтсвенное остаётся понять, почему `'0' == false`. А это потому что при сравнении `'0'` приводится к числу и получается сравнение `0 == false`, а это `true`

Comment: @EzioMercer, `false` тоже к числу приводится.

Comment: _хотелось понять как это работает под капотом_ - в дубликате описан алгоритм сравнения.

Comment: ссылку лучше давать на источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184560/rationale-for-why-javascript-converts-primitive-values-to-numbers-in-operator

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Просто эта часть показалась очевидной, потому не стал дописывать)

Comment: @EzioMercer, не, в таких случаях лучше все расписывать, очевидность - она не всегда верная оказывается :)

Comment: @Grundy И не поспоришь! Согласен, в следующий раз так и сделаю )